# WordPress REST API custom route regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, rest

I am trying to add the following route to the WordPress REST API but I do not know how to use the Regex for it:

/customers?phone=000000000&age=00

I basically want to be able to add a route to query customers (which is a custom post type) by their age and phone number. Can someone help me figure this out please?

Comment: expected match? eg. group 1 or $1 => 00

Comment: I did not quite get what you said, but I want these parameters be available in an associative array with keys phone=> ... and age=> ...

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work.

Regexp:

```
(phone|age)=(\d+)
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$re = '/(phone|age)=(\d+)/';
$str = '/customers?phone=000000000&age=00

';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [phone] => 000000000
    [age] => 00
)
```

Test it: http://ideone.com/jbVvzd

See: https://regex101.com/r/mWx9t1/1